# Vim highlighting between editing sessions

Tags: linux, vim

Is there a way to disable vim from carrying highlighting between editing sessions?

For example, I was looking for the definition of pi (M_PI) in `/usr/include/math.h` and searched `/PI` to find ti real quick.

Now I went to edit a program that had the name of a fellow author on it, Pierre, and the `Pi` in **Pi**erre was highlighted as it had carried voer from my last editing session. What would I put in my .vimrc to disable this weird continuation fo my search term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:set viminfo+=h
```

See:

```
:help viminfo-h
```